# Facebook API - Как получить разрешение user_posts

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

У Facebook есть возможность получать разрешение на получение данных пользователя, но чтобы получить его, надо подавать запрос, который еще и проверяют недели 2 и не факт что одобрят.

Есть ли возможность как-то использовать эти разрешения другим способом, например запрашивать при авторизации как-то? Или это единственный способ? Я использую Python и JavaScript, ни там и не там не выходит.